# Split a string you’ve entered with scanner

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner

I have a problem. I want to type in a string (with Java.util.scanner) with two words. Then I want the program to split my entered string at the whitespace, save both substrings in a seperate variable and make a output in the end.

I know that you can split strings with

```
String s = "Hello World";
String[] = s.split(" ");
```

But it doesnt seem to work when your String is

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

Any help?
Thank you very much

Comment: Your code should work for two input words separated by a single space on the first line.  What is your input?  Maybe, `System.out.println("DEBUG: s=" + s);` could help clarify your problem.

Comment: Your code seems to be ok anyway. What does it mean that the second code doesn't seem to work? Do you get any error? What is the input you provide and what is the output of your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me:

```
String s;
s=sc.nextLine();

String[] words=s.split(" "); 
for(String w:words){  
System.out.print(w+" ");  
}
```

input: `"Hello world"`

output: `"Hello world"`

Comment: actually the output would be "Hello world "

Answer (score 2):

`s.split("\\s+");` will split your string, even if you have multiple whitespace characters (also tab, newline..)

You can also use from `java.util` package

```
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(s.trim());
    String word;
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word = tokens.nextToken();

    }
```

Or from Apache Commons Lang

```
StringUtils.split(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try this way of splitting String that you get from user input:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] strings = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
```

If you simply want to print array containing these  separated strings, you can do it without using any loop, simply by using:

```
Arrays.toString(strings);
```

If you want to have your printed strings to look other way, you can use for it simple loop printing each element or by using `StringBuilder` class and its `append()` method - this way may be faster than looping over longer arrays of strings.